# Trigger click of LinkButton

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, linkbutton, keyup

I'm trying to trigger the click event from a LinkButton with Jquery but it's not working.

I have 2 controls

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCoupon" runat="server" onkeyup="EnterEvent(event, this);"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkValidateCoupon" runat="server" OnClick="lnkValidateCoupon_Click">Validate Coupon</asp:LinkButton>
```

And my js function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function EnterEvent(e, ctrl) {
        var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (keycode === 13) {
            $('[id$=lnkValidateCoupon]').click();
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

When I do a Enter Key inside the textbox, it does nothing. I debugged with F12 with Chrome. I enter into the section click() but it does not trigger the server code of click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the controls in an `asp:Panel` and set the `DefaultButton`.

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="lnkValidateCoupon">
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtCoupon" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkValidateCoupon" runat="server" OnClick="lnkValidateCoupon_Click">Validate Coupon</asp:LinkButton>
</asp:Panel>
```